# DotnetNuke EntityFramework

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am new to .Net nuke, I want to display the records in Repeater control and do some group by functionality and order by functionality from database(Sql server 2008 R2) and I need to use( .Net Nuke 6.0 & Entity Frame Work 4 or 5), I have to follow MVP, please give me any suggestions, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to use DotNetNuke for your own purposes, you can use Entity Framework without any special considerations.

If you are looking to deploy a commercial solution on DotNetNuke, you will want to consider the use of the {objectQualifier} and {databaseOwner} configuration options.  As supporting those is important for widespread DotNetNuke support and not 100% easy to do with EF.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using PetaPoco over entity framework. DotNetNuke 7.x has PetaPoco support built in and, IMHO, is a much better solution.

Learn More: http://www.charlesnurse.com/Blog/tabid/226/EntryId/56/DAL-2-Caching-Scoping-and-Custom-Mappings.aspx